# Why does Laravel have a contract/interface for nearly everything?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was going through the Laravel's Illuminate and I noticed it has an interface for nearly every implementation.

What's the exact purpose of this? Does it have any current use, or is it more to make the framework as scaleable as possible?

Comment: In software engineering contracts are more valuable than their implementations. You can write a class which uses a contract ages before someone actually creates an implementation of the contract and still be able to test it by mocking. Then there's the multiple different implementations (e.g. caching contract using file, redis, db etc)

Comment: So Laravel created the interfaces, to write tests before making the implementations?

Comment: Why the creator of laravel wrote interfaces is a question for him. I can only tell you writing interfaces is just good coding practice for a large software project.

Comment: But in general, people write interfaces so they can write tests before writing the actual implementation?

Comment: That's one of the reasons, yes. Another one is multiple implementations of the same contract (as I mentioned with caching). Another is that you can write code which depends on contracts rather than class implementations so whichever class implements the contract can be plugged in your implementation. There's probably more reasons too.

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks! Can you put this in an answer so I can close the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In software engineering contracts are more valuable than their implementations.

Here's a few reasons:

1. You can test classes which depend on an interface without relying on an interface implementation (which itself may be buggy).
   Example with PHPUnit :

   ```
   //Will return an object of this type with all the methods returning null. You can do more things with the mock builder as well  
   $mockInterface = $this->getMockBuilder("MyInterface")->getMock(); 
   $class = new ClassWhichRequiresInterface($mockInterface);
   //Test class using the mock
   ```
2. You can write a class which uses a contract without needing an implementation e.g.

   ```
   function dependentFunction(MyInterface $interface) {
        $interface->contractMethod(); // Assume it's there even though it's not yet implemented. 
   }
   ```
3. Have a single contract but multiple implementations.

   ```
    interface FTPUploader { /* Contract */ }

    class SFTPUploader implements FTPUploader { /* Method implementation */ }
    class FTPSUploader implements FTPUploader { /* Method implementation */ }
   ```

Laravel offers support of the last one using its service container as follows:

```
$app->bind(FTPUploader::class, SFTPUploader::class); 

resolve(FTPUploader::class); //Gets an SFTPUploader object
```

Then there's also the fact that its easier to document interfaces since there's no actual implementations in there so they're still readable.